# does "she will not give séances as a professional medium" means that she is too professional for giving séances?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

does "she will not give séances as a professional medium" means that she is too professional for giving séances?

> The perfection of the manifestations to be obtained through her
>   depends upon her surroundings, and in proportion as she is in rapport
>   or sympathy with you does she seem receptive of spiritual power. The
>   communications through her are very remarkable, and have come to me
>   frequently from my wife (Estelle), in perfect idiomatic French, and
>   sometimes in Spanish and Italian, whilst she herself is not acquainted
>   with any of these languages. You will understand all this, but these
>   explanations may be necessary for others. As I have said, **she will not
>   give séances as a professional medium**, but I hope she will do all the
>   good she can in furtherance of the great truth, in a quiet way, while
>   she remains in England.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Comment: It means she will not give them for money or as an occupation.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Why did you not just supply that as an answer? I'm new here. And I just want to understand how this works. And the methodology of commenting and answering.

Comment: You could have looked up 'professional' in a dictionary, and that fact makes your question low-quality, and answering low-quality questions is discouraged.

Comment: @Michael Thank you.

Comment: Answers to low-quality questions attract downvotes, even when the answer is correct.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey However, giving exactly the same answer in a comment where it can't be downvoted is acceptable/unacceptable?

Comment: It is fairly common.

Answer (score 0):

No. It only means she will not host seances. It could imply she would still do seances, but not as a professional (or in the capacity of accepting money or compensation). I include this implication because in this context the paragraph applauds her skill as a medium during seances, which is in contradiction to the highlighted phrase.